# How can I truncate tag list to one line using ellipses similar to the one we do for text-overflow?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, preact

I am building a Multiselect component. The component looks like the following. This component is a sample implementation of the concept posted at [Dribbble](https://dribbble.com/shots/5088406-Multiselect-Dropdown):

[image: Multiselect component]

I have got most of the details right. Once thing I cannot figure out is the ellipses pattern (the three dots representing continuation) for overflowing chips (when selected items can no longer fit within one line). **How can I do that?**

1. First preference is CSS only solution.
2. If not plain CSS, then JavaScript based solution would also work.

Comment: do you mean the three dots "..." after co-worklers?

Comment: @Stanley, Yep. The three dots.

Comment: That cant be done in css as it requires if statements. Just use javascript to get the width of the block and if it excedes x width set the element with the three dots to display: block instead of display none